# Simulation of lenslet array

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am trying to simulate [lenslet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenslet)(microlens array). I found a add-on [Camera Generator](https://github.com/Arne-Petersen/Plenoptic-Simulation) where they are simulating microlens array on top of the camera’s sensor. But I want to simulate lenslet array as an independent object.

What I am trying to achieve is a square grid of hexagonal shaped microlens. And I also need to control the focal length of the microlens and the overall size of the lenslet.

Is there any way to simulate lenslet(microlens array) alone?

[image: lenslet]

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide any information on what the result should be here instead of letting us google everything. The Wikipedia article you linked to is basically just saying that a lenslet array is an array of small lenses. Also I'm not willing to install an add-on just to know how an image of a lenslet array would look like... and since I do not know what the result should be I cannot tell you a way to achieve it. What do you mean by lenslet array "alone"? Just getting an array of lenses? Sure, lens model with _Array_ modifier or _Geometry Nodes_. But using them as camera(s)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want to create grid of hexagonal shaped lenses.  I am not using them as cameras. In the add-on, lenslet array comes with the camera. It is not possible to independently control the lenslet from the addon.

Comment: You see, these are all informations that were missing in the question. For example, you want a grid of hexagonal shaped lenses. I've found grids of square lenses as well while googling. Square lenses are of course simpler to arrange in a grid than hexagonal ones. Also I've seen arrays filling square areas as well as circular areas. What do you want? And if square ones for example, how should hexagonal shapes be at the borders? Alternatingly missing one? Or being cut in half for an even border?

Comment: I have attached a picture of the lenslet array I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to fill the a square area with the hexagonal shaped lenses. On the border, alternatively missing one is preferred but other one is also fine.